# How do dual RC filters interact?

Tags: analog, filter

A high-pass RC filter with a corner frequency of 340 Hz can be built with a 47 Ohm resistor and a 10 uF capacitor.
A low-pass RC filter with a corner frequency of 3400 Hz can be built with a 47 Ohm resistor and a 1 uF capacitor.
But what if I combine the filters, using only a single resistor? Will the corner frequencies of the low- and high-pass elements change?

[image]

The input is on the left, the output is on the right, the segment at the bottom is signal ground. The output feeds into a 10K input impedance amplifier input, and the DC blocking of the series capacitor is intentional.

Comment: Sounds like you are creating a bandpass filter

Comment: The corner frequency of the low-pass is calculated using the 47R resistor and 1 microfarad capacitor. The high-pass filter depends on C904 and whatever resistance you put after it. If you short C904 to ground, you'll have a low-pass with a corner frequency calculated with the equivalent capacitance (between C902 and C904) and the value of R902. What will you connect to the output?

Comment: I don't think R902 and C904 form a high pass the way you think they do. C904 forms a high-pass with the input impedance of the next stage (whatever C904 is connected to). What is the input impedance of the next stage? The way the circuit is drawn, the current through C904 will be zero, so the voltage across C904 will be fixed and unchanging, which means it does not act as a filter except at DC.

Comment: By the way, good job on the question. It is clear and you explained enough of your thought process so that we can see what you are thinking. Also, you included a schematic with reference designators. Thank you!

Comment: "The high-pass filter depends on C904 and whatever resistance you put after it." -- it will go into a high-impedance amplifier input. Let's call it 10K. Thanks for reminding me that it's the series resistance that matters for current control! 47R adds to 10K, but the 10K dominates. @Daniel Tork that was the nugget I needed; you should promote your comment to an answer :-)

Comment: @mkeith The average current will be zero, but the instantaneous current will vary by input signal. This is a standard de-coupling output stage for audio line level signals, turning a positive-only output into a swing around ground. And, yes, infinity dB of blocking at DC is a desirable feature!

Comment: Looks like a low pass filter feeding a DC blocking cap into any typical audio amplifier, where the amplifier input's (as you say, could be \$10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$) loading makes up the rest to figure out the bandpass. Nothing unusual here.

Comment: As drawn, with no load on C904, the average and instantaneous current through C904 will be 0 because the C904 is an open circuit. That was my point. That the load will determine the cutoff frequency, not R47. In fact, R47 will form a resistive voltage divider with the load impedance, and attenuate the input at all frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the 10k load resistor, the high-pass time constant is 10k * 10uF = 100 ms. The cutoff frequency is 1/ (100 ms * 2 * pi) = 1.6 Hz. Assuming the DAC output impedance is very low, the low-pass corner would be as you expect. ( 1 / (2 * pi * 47 us)).

The two filters will not interact very much because their corner frequencies are far apart. The DAC output impedance will shift the low-pass filter cutoff frequency downward.

In addition, the series resistance (RDAC and R902) combined with the 10k load impedance will act as a voltage divider in the passband of the high-pass filter. Assuming the series resistances are small, this should be a minor effect. But if you were to alter R902, or if you discover that the DAC output impedance is substantial, this could become significant. Also, if you reduce the 10k load impedance, then the effect could become more significant.

For this reason, if you wish to shift the highpass frequency upward, I suggest you do so by reducing C902.

I would also like to point out that if this circuit will drive an external amplifier, and you cannot control the input impedance of the amplifier, then you may find that the highpass frequency shifts, depending on which amplifier is connected. Hopefully that is OK.

Answer (score 2):

The corner frequency of the low-pass is calculated using the 47Ω resistor and 1μF capacitor. The high-pass filter depends on C904 and whatever resistance you put after it (in your case 10kΩ). If you short C904 to ground, you'll have a low-pass with a corner frequency calculated with the equivalent capacitance (between C902 and C904) and the value of R902.

You are creating a band-pass filter: the low-pass filter attenuates signals with  a frequency higher than its corner frequency(20dB per decade and 6dB per octave) and the high-pass filter attenuates the frequencies smaller than its corner frequency. Anything that has a freq. between these 2 will be passed, but of course some losses will occur since you are using passive filters. You may be able to limit these losses by removing everything and connecting an LC filter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Neither scenario works as a series RC HPF unless you define both source and load impedances.  This applies to all filters. Never assume.

Once you do this then reduction or simplification is possible.

The other criteria for designing ANY filter PROPERLY besides impedance is the STOPBAND attenuation and breakpoint on both ends and group delay or passband ripple or amplitude error tolerance.

### N.B.

LASTLY the input and output impedance(f) must be recognized and defined.  YOu cannot expect an Op Amp to drive large signals into a 47 Ohm load without an understanding of the driver current limit. At the filter breakpoints, the RC components are equal in |impedance| and thus your input looks like ~100Ω load on the DAC which may limit the voltage range or cause load regulation errors. e.g. if source   is 1 Ω then you get 1% load amplitude error at 3400Hz. Also the 10kΩ load causes a gain error of ~47/10k*100%= 0.5%, in addition to component tolerances. But then you may not be fussy here but in commercial designs they are.

But for this simple requirement as stated, LPF T1=47 us= 47Ω*1uF  and HPF T2=4700 us = 0.047uF*10kΩ   where \$f_{-3dB}=\frac{ ~~~1~~~~~~  }{2\pi T}~~\$
[image]

In telephony where Nyquist filters are critical to prevent aliasing noise in the channel, this filter would never be suitable and often dictates specs that result in >= 7th order elliptical LPF's  ( maximally flat group delay) to reject signals above 1/2 the sampling rate of 8kHz.

Group delay is critical in both analog and digital systems.

- In digital, because it affects ISI or Intersymbol Interference where Raised Cosine filters are preferred  or linear phase filters in some cases with (brick wall) Chebyshev filters ( which have very high group delay at cutoff)
- in analog with acoustic feedback to a mic, resonance or howling will occur when the system phase is shifted to positive feedback so phase and amplitude response are both critical and must be specified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You will see in the comments that I added the target input impedance of 10K. I will update the question.

Comment: Yes, the output impedance of the DAC could come into play also. If it is much smaller than 47 Ohms, we can ignore it. Otherwise we should try to estimate it somehow. It will be in series with the 47 Ohms, and can just be added to it.

Comment: The R-DAC must be buffered to <1 Ohm must be  specified with a low gain Op amp in its source. another potential false assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the edit that added more information! In this application, I do in fact not worry about gain error. Also, I explicitly want only the single-pole filter of RC -- this is fed by a 12 bit DAC for sound effects for a hobby robot, going into 1-2 inch speakers with styrofoam cup enclosures. Board space is more a concern than anti-aliasing!

Comment: Since I did your design for you, send coffee and pastry......

Answer (score 0):

The input impedance of the stage loading the first low-pass filter will affect the corner frequency of the combined band-pass filter. If you look at the small sketch below, you can easily estimate the time constant \$\tau\$ of the unloaded \$RC\$ filter by reducing the excitation voltage \$V_{in}\$ to 0 V. You have \$\tau_1=R_1C_1\$ and you form a low-pass filter whose transfer function is \$H(s)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ in which \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau_1}\$.

[image]

If you now load the filter by \$R_2\$, the new time constant becomes \$\tau_2=(R_1||R_2)C_1\$ and considering the dc gain \$H_0=\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_1}\$, the new transfer function becomes \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ in which \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau_2}\$. So you see that changing \$R_2\$, you not only modify the attenuation but also the corner frequency. If you now replace \$R_2\$ by a high-pass \$RC\$ filter, you have the below circuit:

[image]

The new time constants are determined by reducing the excitation to 0 V again and by "looking" at the resistances driving the caps. in this mode. Summing the two time constants leads to determining \$b_1\$ in the denominator \$D(s)\$ of the newly-formed transfer function: \$b_1=\tau_1+\tau_2=R_1C_1+C_2(R_1+R_2)\$. The term \$b_2\$ is given by replacing \$C_1\$ by a short circuit and determining the new resistance driving \$C_2\$: you have \$\tau_{12}=C_2R_2\$. Then, you combine \$\tau_1\$ and \$\tau_{12}\$ to form \$b_2=\tau_1\tau_{12}=R_1C_2R_1C_2\$. You have \$D(s)=1+s(\tau_1+\tau_2)+s^2\tau_1\tau_{12}=1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2\$ and you determine \$Q\$ and \$\omega_0\$ by a quick identification. The numerator is obtained by calculating simple gains \$H\$ in which the caps are either all open (dc condition and \$H_0=0\$) or alternatively shorted (\$H^1\$ and \$H^2\$) or both shorted (\$H^{12}\$). The numerator is thus defined by \$N(s)=H_0+s(H^1\tau_1+H^2\tau_2)+s^2H^{12}\tau_1\tau{12}=R_2C_2\$. The complete transfer function can be re-arranged under the following low-entropy form: \$H(s)=H_{00}\frac{1}{1+Q(\frac{s}{\omega_0}+\frac{\omega_0}{s})}\$ in which \$Q\$ and \$\omega_0\$ are defined in the below Mathcad shot:

[image]

and it gives the following dynamic responses with arbitrary values for \$C_2\$ and \$R_2\$:

[image]

Finally, you have to realize that your DAC output is directly loaded by the input impedance of the cascaded \$RC\$ filter. I have derived the \$Z_{in}\$ below and no surprise, as \$s\$ approaches infinity, the first resistance sets the input impedance.

[image]

Considering its fairly low magnitude, you may have some significant current flowing at high frequency and you could perhaps consider increasing your \$R_{902}\$ value while recomputing the other elements to keep the same dynamic response. You can see that I derived all these expression by inspection, without writing a line of algebra. This is the power of the [FACts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371).

Comment: Yes, asking the DAC to push > 40 mA into a 2V swing seems a little much. 470 Ohm R902 and 0.1 uF C902 would work better for that case. And 0.1 uF film caps are smaller/cheaper than 1.0 uF.

Comment: If you want a comprehensive analysis, the capacitor hosts several parasitic terms. One of them is the equivalent series resistance or ESR usually labelled \$r_C\$ and it introduces a zero in the low-pass filter transfer function. Its value is usually given in the capacitor data-sheet. The additional zero is located at \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{r_CC_1}\$. You may want to account for its role also.